# overriding _rendermenu in jquery autocomplete throws js error

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I tried to override _rendermenu in jquery autocomplete. The list is getting generated but every time I hover over the results i get the following js error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in jquery-ui.js

the code  used is

```
$(function () {
var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme",
                "AA",
                "BB",
                "CC",
                "DD",
                "EE",
                "FF",
                "GG",
                "HH",
                "II",
                "JJ",
                "KK"
            ];


   var atComplete=$( "#autoCompleteText" ).autocomplete({
        delay:0,
        source:availableTags,
             autoFocus: true,
             minLength: 0,
             appendTo: "#result"          
}).focus(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
 }).data('ui-autocomplete');
   atComplete._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
            var that = this;
            $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                    that._renderItem( ul, item );
            });
    };

    atComplete._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        console.log("item in render item:",item);
            return $("<li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [API docs for `_renderMenu`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderMenu) you'll see the reason you're getting an error:

> Creation of the individual <li> elements should be delegated to _renderItemData(), which in turn delegates to the _renderItem() extension point.

You're using `renderItem()` directly. This means that you're not actually binding item data to the `.data('ui-autocomplete-item')` cache, which the widget attempts to read when drawing the menu -- but since it's undefined, the page is throwing an error.

To fix it all you need to do is change the call to `_renderItem` to call `_renderItemData` instead:

```
atComplete._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this;
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        });
};
```